# ethX:0 equivalent in ensX

Tags: networking

I'm trying to configure a failover IP in a Ubuntu 16.04 but I have `ens3` where it usually was `eth0`.

Previously I followed this [guide](http://guias.ovh.pt/AdicionarAliasIp) and I added to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
post-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0:X IP.DE.FAIL.OVER netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast IP.DE.FAIL.OVER post-down /sbin/ifconfig eth0:X down
```

I tried doing in the terminal (to test):

```
ifconfig post-up  ens3:0 94.23.76.87 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 94.23.76.87
```

but the result was:

```
ens3:0: Unknown host
```

I know this is the new naming but I can't find any documentation on it (even the man ifconfig still uses eth0...

My config file is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
```

How should I do this?

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: It's just ens3, without anything after it (no :0)

Comment: But if eth0:0 is ens3 and eth0 is ens3 how do I assign multiple IPs to the same network interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The network card configuration file of Ubuntu system is `/etc/network/interfaces.`

In the terminal run:

```
exec sudo -i
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

Sample output:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
```

As you see in the above output, the Interface is DHCP enabled.

To assign an additional address, for example 94.23.76.87/24

Edit file /etc/network/interfaces:

```
exec sudo -i
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add additional IP address.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp

iface ens3 inet static
address 94.23.76.87/24
```

Save and close the file.

Run the following file to take effect the changes without rebooting:

```
exec sudo -i
ifdown ens3
ifup ens3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked! Just something important: My machine is remote so ifdown ens3 made lost the connection. Restarting the VM so the ifup would be by systemctl resolved it.